# Need help converting SQL query to LINQ statement for use in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

This is the query I need to convert to a LINQ statement for use inside my ASP.NET MVC 3 project. I'm not all that good with LINQ yet so I'm going to need some help please.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT a.GalleryID GalleryID_A, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, b.*
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate
                            ORDER BY b.MediaThumb DESC) AS Rn
    FROM Media b
         INNER JOIN Galleries A ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
),

CTE2 AS (
  SELECT a.GalleryID GalleryID_A, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, b.*, 1 Rn
   FROM Media b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Galleries A ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
)

SELECT * FROM CTE where rn = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM CTE2
  WHERE rn = 1
    AND galleryid is null

ORDER BY MediaID DESC
```

This was my solution.

```
var Results = DB.Database.SqlQuery<WhatsNew>
                (@" WITH CTE AS (
                    SELECT a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, b.*,  
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate 
                    ORDER BY b.MediaThumb DESC) AS Rn
                    FROM Media b
                    INNER JOIN Galleries A
                    ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
                ), 
                CTE2 AS
                (
                    SELECT a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, b.*,  
                    1 Rn
                    FROM Media b
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Galleries A
                    ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
                )
                SELECT * FROM CTE where rn = 1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE rn = 1 and galleryid is null
                ORDER BY MediaID DESC ");
```

Comment: Is it even possible to convert this SQL query to a LINQ query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your query as a view in sql, say "MyView" and then call that from your MVC project.

```
return db.ExecuteStoreQuery<YourEntityType>("SELECT * FROM MyView");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are just learning linq and want to convert a complicated query like this I would recommend using this tool

http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CTEs only for paging, you can use the [`Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) and [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906) extensions.

```
var page = (from a in _context.Set<Media>()
    orderby a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate
    select a)
    .Skip(page * size).Take(size);
```

Or use [PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList).

```
var page = (from a in _context.Set<Media>()
    orderby a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate
    select a)
    .ToPagedList(page, size);
```